# My while loop isn't working

Tags: python

This is just part of my code and i am not sure why my while loop doesn't let the user try again. Please help me!

```
answer3 = True
while answer3:
    if answer2.lower() == "no" or answer2.lower() == "nah":
        print ("Okay then ... Bye.")
        sys.exit()
    elif answer2 == "Yes".lower() or answer2.lower() == "yeah" or answer2.lower() == "yes":
        print ("Okay then ... \n")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer! Try again!\n")
    break
```

Comment: Do not include images of your code; paste it in the text box, then highlight it and press Ctrl+K to indent it correctly.

Comment: OK thanks @Aurora0001

Comment: @AsifKhan are you sure you dont want to exit in the loop when the answer is yes?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the break, your problem is that it is stopping after the first iteration.

What is happening is that the break instruction is used to abandon the loop. In your code, you set your first variable to True and expect to continue looping while the condition is not met.

The code just evaluates the conditions and the last sentence (the break) instructs the while to exit, that is what you want to avoid.

Use this code to check the correct behavior:

```
import sys

answer3 = True
while answer3:
    answer2 = raw_input("introduce your option: ")

    if answer2.lower() == "no" or answer2.lower() == "nah":
        print ("Okay then ... Bye.")
        sys.exit()
    elif answer2 == "Yes".lower() or answer2.lower() == "yeah" or answer2.lower() == "yes":
        print ("Okay then ... \n")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer! Try again!\n")
```

Comment: That is correct the break is preventing any repetition.

Comment: This is technically correct, but it would be a good idea to explain *why* removing the `break` fixes the issue. The OP probably is still a beginner and won't understand fully without a more detailed explanation.

Comment: check with the example code I've just put, you will see it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @maki

Answer (score 1):

The break function exits your while loop, so even if answer3 still has the value  True, it will stop the loop after the end of it's first cycle. Remove break and it shall work.

> It terminates the current loop and resumes execution at the next
>   statement, just like the traditional break statement in C.
>
> The most common use for break is when some external condition is
>   triggered requiring a hasty exit from a loop. The break statement can
>   be used in both while and for loops.
>
> If you are using nested loops, the break statement stops the execution
>   of the innermost loop and start executing the next line of code after
>   the block.

[image]

Comment: I've tried removing the break but when i do it just keeps on printing out the same thing over and over again

Comment: Because the answer2 input is outside of the loop, and so it will always hold the same value.

Comment: But why are you using a while loop if your interest is checking answer2's value once, in order to either quit or proceed running the program?

Comment: Just add the answer2 input inside the loop, at the beggining and it will work.

Comment: Its because i want the user to be able to try again if they have input an answer that isn't yes or no

Comment: import sys

answer3 = True
while answer3:
    answer2 = raw_input("introduce your option: ")

    if answer2.lower() == "no" or answer2.lower() == "nah":
        print ("Okay then ... Bye.")
        sys.exit()
    elif answer2 == "Yes".lower() or answer2.lower() == "yeah" or answer2.lower() == "yes":
        print ("Okay then ... \n")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer! Try again!\n")

Comment: (Why can't I remove/edit comments?) That worked for me

Comment: I'm not sure why but when i try raw_input it always says that it isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Other than removing the break as other answer suggests you need to again get the value of answer2.

Other than that I believe you may also want to break from loop in case answer is yes

```
answer3 = True
while answer3:
    answer2 = str(input("Enter your answer no/yes:"))
    if answer2.lower() == "no" or answer2.lower() == "nah":
        print ("Okay then ... Bye.")
        sys.exit()
    elif answer2 == "Yes".lower() or answer2.lower() == "yeah" or answer2.lower() == "yes":
        print ("Okay then ... \n")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer! Try again!\n")
```